# Can one pagetracker object send data to multiple Google Analytics account?

Tags: asynchronous, google-analytics

[Google's sample code](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html#MultipleCommands) shows multiple accounts can track a page using different tracker object

```
_gaq.push(
  ['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-1'],
  ['_trackPageview'],
  ['b._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-2'],
  ['b._trackPageview']
);
```

But would it be ok if we just use the same tracker object like below since the API call is being queued and executed on *[first-in-first-out](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html#Syntax)* basis?

```
var _gaAccounts = ['UA-XXXXX-1', 'UA-XXXXX-2'];
  for(var i=0; i<_gaAccounts.length ; i++)
{
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', _gaAccounts[i]],
             ['_trackPageview']);
}
```

Comment: It might be OK (would have to be tested), but isn't it more efficient to use the one push method Google advocates rather than 4 pushes from the loop?

Answer (score 0):

As per @jen's comment, it's far more efficient to do a single push to Google than to do 4 individual pushes. Remember that these are calls to a remote server, so best to keep them to a minimum.

In theory, your code ***should*** work and that's backed up by [Brian Katz's post here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=360aa3eb434e9ef1&hl=en). In practice, however, I think there's a danger of you overwriting your cookies and screwing up your analytics. Multiple trackers continually cause problems if not configured correctly - so why add an extra unsupported step?

Comment: I don't think putting everything into a single push is any more efficient as it still causes 2 requests to Google instead of 4 you mentioned. The push is to the queue not Google.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I think there's still a problem. The documentation on push() here is better: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApi_gaq.html#_gaq.push

If you use an unnamed tracked, functions like _trackPageview will be executed on the default tracker. But the setAccount function creates a new tracking object every time it's invoked [http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setAccount], so you might still end up with the situation where functions are executed using the wrong tracking object. Testing needed!